# Efficiency with multiple asyncio readers and a single writer (different thread)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I would like to combine threading and asyncio with some synchronisation.

For example: A thread write-combines frames from a camera into some variable or buffer. Multiple readers (asyncio or threads) are woken on each write to take the latest available frame.

I have tried deriving from the `asyncio.Event` to no avail.

```
class EventThreadSafe(asyncio.Event):
    def set(self):
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(super().set)
```

Is there a mechanism that does this already (https://github.com/aio-libs/janus?) or how is best to implement it?

Comment: Do you have a minimal/runnable example that demonstrates what you'd like to achieve? How exactly did your `EventThreadSafe` class fail? Also, do you really need **both** threaded and asyncio consumers? It sounds like it should be one or the other, depending on architecture, but never both. (I'm not saying it's wrong, but it has a definite "design smell".)

Comment: Thanks - https://pastebin.com/XJ5J1Vn1  It fails by constantly reading after the event is unset for the first time: although to be honest I didn't expect it to work.  The reason for the writer thread is that the writer thread is slow (IO, processing, etc) I didn't want the aio loop to stall while I waiting for the frames to come in and be processed.  They are then streamed out with multi-part mjpg over http.  I didn't use a separate thread readers as well as the aio ones, but I would still like to know how to do it efficiently should the occasion arise.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue), however it is not thread safe, just task safe.  If you want thread safe use [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue), however this is not task safe as it will block your thread.  Personally for multiprocess I use a [0MQ Push-Pull Pattern](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html), which feeds to/from a `asyncio.Queue` adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure the push/pull pattern is what I want; I think what I am describing is closer to publish/subscribe.  I also want it to be both threadsafe and task safe but able to write-combine the results so not every subscriber need get every frame.  So, one frame that comes in might be read by 2 of 3 asyncio tasks, then the next frame might be read by all 3 asyncio tasks.

Comment: ya push/pull is for multiple publish, one message for subscribe, publish subscribe is multiple publish, everyone gets the same objects. There are various patterns.  See here for using pyzmq: https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/patterns.html.  If you're inproc make sure to use the `inproc` socket.  Probably your best bet!